# I need a method (methods will have same return value, but distinct params) like a param. What can i do?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, parameter-passing, func

I have the next code:

```
public byte[] A(int i){//do something}

public byte[] B(string a) { //do something}

public void useAMethod()
{
  //Previous code
  byte[] array = A(0);
  //final code using array 
}

public void useBMethod()
{
  //Previous code
  byte[] array = B("test");
  //final code using array 
}
```

Like you can see, i have two methods with same return value but differents params
I would like something like:

```
public void useAnyMethod([method] methodToUse)
{
  //Previous code
  byte[] array = methodToUse;
  //final code using array 
}
```

To use like:

```
useAnyMethod(A(0));
useAnyMethod(B("test"));
```

is it posiible??

Thanks

Comment: Does the method have to be executed exactly between `Previous code` and `final code`? Otherwise, you could make `useAMethod` take a parameter of type `byte[]` (the result of one of the methods).

Comment: If I were you I'd provide some background information on why you need this; I have a feeling there are more elegant solutions to your problem.

Comment: @NicoSchertler the method have to be executed exactly between Previous code and final code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it the `byte[] =` is some sort of internal assignment?

If so

```
public void useAnyMethod(byte[] result) { 

   byte[] = result;  // This is not actually valid because you don't have a variable name after byte[]¬
}

useAnyMethod(a(0));
useAnyMethod(b("fish"));
```

useAnyMethod doesn't actually call the method it just accepts the return value of the method which the runtime will call first to get the result.

Alternatively if you are determined to used a delegate

```
public void useAnyMethod(Func<byte[]> method) {
    byte[] = method();
}

useAnyMethod(()=>A(0));
useAnyMEthod(()=>B("test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a basic overloading candidate to me.

```
public void DoSomething(int data) 
{
    var bytes = // convert int to bytes here
    DoSomething(bytes)
}

public void DoSomething(string data)
{
    var bytes = // convert string to bytes here
    DoSomething(bytes)
}

public void DoSomething(byte[] data) 
{
}
```

Comment: The example is a simplification. My real methods have a lot of params...thanks anyway